# Unable to enclose JSON values in quotes dynamically Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am having a very hard enclosing variable values in a key in quotes in a JSON string in Swift.
I have a key that has one or two value in it depending on some non relevant logic. If I hard code the values in the JSON String as follows;

```
let jsonMessage: [String: Any] = [
...
"options": [
"Option1", "Option2"
]
...
```

Everything works fine and this is how I need it. The issue is that at times I just need to use one or the other values and not both so I need to build the value. (Or even the whole key:value pair)

I thought I could do this by just doing something like:

```
let option1var = "Option1"
let option2var = "Option2"
"options": [
"\"\(option1var)\"","\"\(option2var)\""
]
```

but that doesn't escape the backslash escape characters and outputs as;

```
"options": [
"\Option1\","\"Option2\"
]
```

If I try to not use the escape characters, but can't since the comma breaks the string the output is as follows;

```
"options": [
option1var,option2var  //String breaks at comma
]
```

Which is no good as I need the values enclosed in quotes

I also tried creating the key as a Dictionary of same type [String: Any] and inserting the whole value like this;

```
options = ["options": "\"Option1\",\"Option2\""]
```

but then it tells me it's looks for a string value instead of a dictionary value.

I've tried a number of other variation but I either can't enclose the entire value in a string due to the quotes or if I use escaping characters, they just appear in the string.

I'm worried that I just can't see the forest for the trees and am missing something obvious but I just cannot figure out what it is and any help would be super appreciated.

Tried one more failed attempt as follows;

```
options = option1var + "," + option2var
```

Came out as;

```
"options": "Option1,Option2"  //Need entries separated and enclosed
```

Comment: Just write `"options": [option1var, option2var]` in Swift. That said, you should probably use `Codable` instead.

Comment: @Sweeper  Of course I didn't try that.... This particular case has a JSON string with mostly hardcoded values except for this key and one more which is why I'm using the string instead of codable but I appreciate the suggestion. Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a JSON array containing two strings, "Option1" and "Option2", so naturally, you should make a Swift array containing those two strings, which are stored in `option1var` and `option2var`. That is:

```
[option1var, option2var]
```

Note that the quotes are not part of the string you want to encode. You see them in JSON only because they are part of the JSON syntax. The JSON encoder will take care of adding those quotes. You should not add them in your Swift code, i.e. this is incorrect:

```
["\"\(option1var)\"","\"\(option2var)\""]
```

This is an array containing strings that starts and ends with quotes.